# ms crm queryexpression with linkentiites

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am using MS crm 2013 on premise. I am working on a console app where I need to do a retrievemultiple.

```
QueryExpression queexp = new QueryExpression();

ConditionExpression conexp1;
conexp1 = new ConditionExpression();
conexp1.AttributeName = "new_memberid";           
conexp1.Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal;
conexp1.Values.Add(id);
```

Query has linkentities:

```
queexp.LinkEntities.Add(linkEntityAccount);
queexp.LinkEntities.Add(linkEntityArbet);
```

If I remove the above two lines about linkentities, the query works fine.Otherwise , it returns 0 results.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify clearly what LinkEntities you want to add. For example:

```
//Create a query expression specifying the link entity alias and the columns of the link entity that you want to return

QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression();
qe.EntityName = "account";
qe.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet();
qe.ColumnSet.Columns.Add("name");

qe.LinkEntities.Add(new LinkEntity("account", "contact", "primarycontactid", "contactid", JoinOperator.Inner));
qe.LinkEntities[0].Columns.AddColumns("firstname", "lastname");
qe.LinkEntities[0].EntityAlias = "primarycontact";

EntityCollection ec = _orgService.RetrieveMultiple(qe);
```

2nd approach is using LINQ:

```
OrganizationServiceContext orgSvcContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(xProxy);
var result = from c in orgSvcContext.CreateQuery("entityname")
    //where....
    select c;
EntityCollaction xEntityCol = result;
```

Comment: Ofcourse, I have that I did not add it here in the question. I think it is some microsoft bug,

Comment: What you metioned is in my code already. But, always 0 records are retieved. When I remove the linkentities I get one record as expected

Comment: In the sample you mentioned, there is no condition expression. That's why it will work. Try adding linkentiites and a specific conditionexpression. There will be 0 records retrieved

Comment: Have you heard about the xrm fetcher?

Comment: No, I knw using fetchexpression. But not xrm fetcher.I was curious to knw why this simple thing does not work.

Comment: organizationProxy.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(m_Fetchtstring));

Where m_Fetchstring == <fetch mapping='logical' count='1'><entity name='incident'><all-attributes/> <filter type='and'> <condition attribute='title' operator='eq' value='Test CreateIncident' /></filter></entity></fetch>

Comment: the xrm fetcher is a class which generates my m_Fetchstring ;)

Comment: I figured this out. If the linkentity lookup is blank then crmservice retrieves nothing at all.I think Microsoft has a wrong design here, it should retrieve the record with other columns.